# Simple list function in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to append values (`x`) to a list if the numbers are divisible by 2 and then print out that list.  Seems pretty simple.  The following runs but returns `None`:

```
x = []

def test():
    while x in range(0,100):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x.append()
print(test())
```

Comment: return the list

Comment: it cannot work, `append` doesn't have an argument.

Comment: also, try `list(range(0,100,2))` instead of this cumbersome code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems and Fixes

Your have several problems with your code:

- You named your list `x` and your iterate variable `x`.
- You never append a value to your list.
- You never return a list from `test`. Rather than `append`ing to a global list, make a local list in `test` and return *that* list.
- You're using a `while` loop when you should be using a `for` loop.

After the above changes, you code look likes:

```
def test():
    even_numbers = []
    for number in range(0, 100):
        if number % 2 == 0:
            even_numbers.append(number)
    return even_numbers

print(test())
```

### Improvements

Note there are better ways to do this. In this case, a list comprehension is a better choice. List comprehensions can be used to avoid the common pattern of building a list of values - such as your case:

```
def test():
    return [n for n in range(0, 100) if n % 2 == 0]

print(test())
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `for` to iterate a range - not `while`.
2. You have ambiguous meaning to `x` - both as iteration variable and as a list.
3. You need to pass the value to `append`.
4. You need to return a value so it would be printed through the print statement - otherwise `None` is the default.

Fixed:

```
x = []

def test():
    for i in range(0,100):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x.append(i)
    return x

print(test())
```

Other notes:

- You can only use this once. The next call for `test` would return a list twice the size, since `x` is a global variable. I believe this is unintended and can be solved by putting the `x = []` inside the function.
- A list comprehension like `[x for x in range(100) if x % 2 == 0]` would be much better.

Comment: your problem forgot to give it x

Comment: @PokestarFan huh?

Comment: it needs to supply x.

Comment: @PokestarFan not necessarily. see my comments.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should pass the variable to the function and return it from the function instead of relying on global variables:

```
def test(x):
    ...
    return x
```

However `while x in range(0, 100)` won't work because it will check if `x` (an empty list) is contained in the `range` object. But the `range` only contains numbers so the `while` loop body will never execute. So you could use a `for`-loop instead:

```
def test(x):
    for i in range(0, 100):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x.append(i)
    return x
```

But you could also use the fact that `range` supports a `step` and remove the `if` by just using `step=2`:

```
def test(x):
    for i in range(0, 100, 2):
        x.append(i)
    return x
```

At this point you could even just `extend` (append an iterable to) the list:

```
def test(x):
    x.extend(range(0, 100, 2))
    return x
```

Comment: Ah, nice idea with the `step` argument in `range`. That was an obvious improvement I missed. +1

Comment: @ChristianDean Yeah, but I've just seen that it was suggested by Jean-François Fabre  in the comments on the question. So I can't take full credit for that.

Comment: you guys are great, thanks everyone for the quick replies.  Makes sense.

Comment: @MSeifert Oh, I see. I guess I'll up-vote his comment then.

Comment: @MSeifert stupid question, but that last example you showed...how would i print that?  I added print(x) right under return x but it didn't do anything..

Comment: You print what the function returns. First you create an empty list `x=[]` and then you can use `print(test(x))`. Or you can pass an empty list to the function directly: `print(test([]))` :-]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a step of 2 to avoid if tests :

```
x = []
def test():
   for i in range(0,100,2):
      x.append(i)
   return x
```

Or use a list comprehension :

```
x = []
def test():
   x = [i for i in range(0,100,2)]
   return x
```

Or use the range it's self as a list:

```
x = []
def test()
   x = list(range(0,100,2))
   return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your inner x variable for simplicity. Use x.append(n) instead of x.append(). Finally, print the variable not the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should either change the list variable or the iteration variable(x in while loop) . and append function works like this `list.append(value)`.